# Upload file/s on web share

Tags: powershell

On Windows, is it possible to upload a file to a webshare without use `net use` or `New-PSDrive`? (I have PowerShell 3.0 available)

Now I use:

```
net use Z: http://share.net/mypath/my2path/ /user:<domain\username> <password>
```

Or:

```
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root http://share.net/mypath/my2path/ -Credential domain\user
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not say what type of file you wanted to upload, you may need to add the -ContentType switch to the command. Change the fileToUpload variable to be the path to your file. Otherwise, this should work:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
$fileToUpload = "c:\temp\myfile.txt"
$uri = "http://share.net/mypath/my2path/"

Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri -Method Put -Infile $fileToUpload -Credential $credentials
```